# Clearing a kendo Spreadsheet but not the headers

Tags: kendo-ui

Keno spreadsheets are new and the documentation is very scarce.

I'm trying to do something relatively simple.

I have a spreadsheet with stylized headers like this:

```
this.sheetsHeader = [
            {
                name: "ProductsEntry",
                rows: [
                    {
                        height: 15,
                        cells: [
                            {
                                value: "Name",
                                bold: "true",
                                background: "#00435e",
                                textAlign: "center",
                                color: "white",
                                fontSize: 14,
                            }, {
                                value: "Type",
                                bold: "true",
                                background: "#00435e",
                                textAlign: "center",
                                color: "white",
                                fontSize: 14,
                            },
                            {
                                value: "Currency",
                                bold: "true",
                                background: "#00435e",
                                textAlign: "center",
                                color: "white",
                                fontSize: 14,
                            },
                            {
                                value: "Rate",
                                bold: "true",
                                background: "#00435e",
                                textAlign: "center",
                                color: "white",
                                fontSize: 14
                            },
                            {
                                value: "StartDate",
                                bold: "true",
                                background: "#00435e",
                                textAlign: "center",
                                color: "white",
                                fontSize: 14,
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                columns: [
                    { width: 200 },
                    { width: 200 },
                    { width: 90 },
                    { width: 90 },
                    { width: 110 }
                ]
            }
        ];
```

and that gets initialized the normal way:

```
    $("#spreadsheet").kendoSpreadsheet({
        toolbar: false,
        sheetsbar: false,
        sheets: that.sheetsHeader
    });
```

Then later I have an event that clears the spreadsheet but I want to leave the headers intact.

If I do this:

```
var sheet = spreadsheet.activeSheet();
sheet.range(kendo.spreadsheet.SHEETREF).clear();
```

It wipes out the headers and leaves the sheet entirely empty.

I tried re-adding the headers in many different ways but nothing worked for me.

Aftear clearing the spreadsheet I tried:

```
 sheet.fromJSON(that.sheetsHeader[0].rows);
```

I also tried deleting the sheet and re-adding it:

```
 spreadsheet.removeSheet(0);
 spreadsheet.insertSheet(that.sheetsHeader);
```

Nothing really worked so far and there's no documentation for this sort of scenario. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did it:

```
sheet.fromJSON(that.sheetsHeader[0]);
```

I really wish they provided some documentation though. It wasn't very intuitive.